# Subtraction between features before performing PCA and training a classification model

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, feature-engineering, differences

In my dataset, I've created moving averages for historical indicators.

Is it pertinent to perform subtraction between those moving averages before PCA?

My **stats/calculus feeling**: as PCA is a linear transformation, it is useless.

My **business feeling**: the difference between those moving averages could be helpful for a model (showing a change of trend).

**My experience**: I tried it, and I saw a little increase in the number of the components with a given kept variance threshold in the PCA model, but no improvement for the final classification model.

Also, what about date subtraction to get the delay between two events? Should I only represent the date, for example as the number of seconds from a given date?

Comment: If your data are time series price returns for assets, then PCA has been introduced as a way to reduce the e.g. #days down to lower dimensions, as well as reduce the #assets down to a lower dimension.  I would probably not take simple moving or exponential moving averages before PCA, but you could.  Remember, you'll be introducing lag into your system by using averages, so look at John Ehler's (free) super smoother (with a default period of 10, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KyiS_7Lscyo), or Jurik Research's JMA (commercial), which are both low-lag.

Comment: Thanks for the ressource, however my data is not time series price returns for assets. Furthermore, I ask this question as a more **general purpose** when I start to do **feature engineering** on a problem, **regardless of the domain** (The moving averages indicators was just an example)

Comment: Okay, then for the general question, I would never by default average any data before running PCA on it, irrespective of focusing on objects, features, or domain.